OR condition in the indexed column slows Performance
I have a query related to MySQL execution time. Say I have a table(A) with 5Cr records and table(B) with 7Cr Records. Table B has an Foreign Key(FK) reference for Table A.(id column)
I have two queries where one executed in 20 seconds and another executed in 5ms.
20 Sec Query :
 SELECT     min(table a.id),
           TABLE b.COLUMN
FROM       TABLE a
INNER JOIN TABLE b
ON         TABLE a.id = TABLE b.id
AND        b.id2(indexed COLUMN) = '12345'
WHERE      b.COLUMN IN (value)
OR         a.id     IN(idslist)
GROUP BY   b.id2,
           b.COLUMN
           -- > Here the B.column is also an indexed column. 

5ms Sec Query :
 SELECT     min(table a.id),
           TABLE b.COLUMN
FROM       TABLE a
INNER JOIN TABLE b
ON         TABLE a.id = TABLE b.id
AND        b.id2(indexed COLUMN) = '12345'
WHERE      b.COLUMN IN (value)
GROUP BY   b.id2,
           b.COLUMN -- > Removed A.id from the criteria. 

Not sure why this difference. Can someone help me finding the cause?
Expected that A.id is a Primary Key(pk) column and won't affect the performance.

Run EXPLAIN for both queries and it should be clear what is going on. If not, update your question with the two query plans. Please avoid using locale specific units (Cr) as many of us do not know what they are (1 Crore = 10,000,000?).

Avoid using OR. Instead, split this into separate queries for each condition, and combine them with UNION.

Yeah, OR is usually an optimization-killer.
Is b.COLUMN IN (value) always a single "value"?  So it could be written b.COLUMN = value?
This might help:
b:  INDEX(id2, column)   -- this may avoid the sort

It seems like the result of the slower query will includes what id2 != 12345 and/or COLUMN NOT IN (value); is that to be expected?
